# Список из итераторов на этот же список

Tags: c++, итераторы

Как сделать список, содержащий итераторы на этот же список? Такой код, очевидно, не компилируется:

```
typedef std::list<RuleIter> RuleList;
typedef RuleList::const_iterator RuleIter;
```

Comment: Каков сценарий использования подобного подхода? Похоже на «ошибку молотка».

Comment: @Arhad если не просто список, а список списков итераторов, то так можно моделировать графы, а если список списков списков итераторов, то КС грамматику. Но проблема та же самая.

Comment: Есть возможность использовать невладеющие (сишные) указатели вместо итераторов? Просто итераторы предполагают итерирование (проход) по массиву, а у вас, похоже, просто статичная отсылка к элементу.

Comment: @Arhad итераторы могут использоваться и для доступа, не только для просмотра элементов контейнера. Да и указатели могут применяться для «итерирования». Вообще мне хотелось бы использовать средства C++, где это возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Напрямую, похоже, никак, ибо невозможно сформулировать правильный синтаксис.

Однако начиная с С++17 были переработаны (ослаблены) требования на *полноту* (completeness) типа элемента списка, что теперь позволяет нам поступить так

```
struct RuleListElement;
typedef std::list<RuleListElement> RuleList;
typedef RuleList::const_iterator RuleIter;

struct RuleListElement
{
  RuleIter it;
};
```

Некоторые до-С++17 реализации соглашались компилировать такие объявления, но формально до С++17 на тип элемента стандартного контейнера накладывалось требование полноты.

Comment: Спасибо, мне тоже пришла в голову эта идея. Но так всё-таки лишний уровень вложенности. Что если унаследовать `RuleListElement` от `RuleList::const_iterator` ? Можно как-нибудь так сделать, какие тут подвохи?